# Selenium-webdriver doesn't work well on github action

Tags: selenium-webdriver, github-actions

It was running fine on local and Jenkin, but when I migrate my project to github action.

it always displays

"Cannot read property'driver' of undefined"

I think my environment setting is all same, node and npm version are all same

btw I am using saucelab working on automation test

Comment: could you be more specific in what you are doing -- where is it failing, and how are you building everything for github actions?

Comment: I am using saucelab to run functional tests and accessibility test

Comment: Please include your GHA workflow and the complete error trace in your question.